# How to Reduce the size of a speccific format string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex, byte

I have designed a 2 Pass Assembler for my project. The output is in Hexadecimal form i.e. 15 is 0F.

I am working with ComPort and to send "0F" over the line it should be sent as String. 
But the problem is that I can only receive 1 byte on the other end and `sizeOf("0F") > 1` byte .
There is no way of decompressing data on the other end and I need to do all work on my end and still i want to receive "0F" on the other end.
Can i do this if yes then how?

I did this to get the hexadecimal string :

```
String.format("{0:X2}",15);
```

---

In addition,

```
using System.IO.Ports; 
private SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort(); 
comPort.Write("0F");
```

On the receiving end I have a 8-bit processor which have a 1byte * 256 blocks i.e. 256 bytes. "0F" when received is received as 2 bytes and cannot be stored in a single block of 1 byte. So I want "0F" to be of 1 byte.

Comment: a) how do you send it? b) which byte is received?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Each `char` in a `string` is _two_ bytes in itself. If you can send only one byte, maybe you simply want: `(byte)15`

Comment: using System.IO.Ports;
private SerialPort comPort  = new SerialPort();
comPort.Write("0F");

On the receiving end I have a 8-bit processor which have a 1byte * 256 blocks i.e. 256 bytes. 
"0F" when received is received as 2 bytes and cannot be stored in a single block of 1 byte. So I want "0F" to be of 1 byte.

If still it's not clear please feel free to ask i will clarify...

Comment: @HenkHolterman plz refer to the comment above..

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen plz refer to the comment above

Comment: @AjeyPratapSingh - please use the _edit_ link under your question. Comments are hard to read and easily deleted.

Comment: ok @HenkHolterman
i m kinda new and will take some time to understand the trends of posting and replying,,, Kindly help me in getting through with this plz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
    // create buffer
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

    // put values you need to send to buffer
    buffer[0] = 0x0f;

    // ... add another bytes if you need...

    // send them
    var comPort = new SerialPort();
    comPort.Write(buffer, 0, 1); // 0 is buffer offset, 1 is number of bytes to write
```

Comment: I used your code bt the only problem is that the data received is in Integer form i.e. 0F is received as 15.

Comment: `0F == 15`. There is no problem.

Comment: 0F == 15 bt i don't have any mechanism to change it back into hexadecimal. The receiving side is pure hardware and it can only work on 0F not on 15.

Comment: Hex is not hardware, it's a string. `15` and `0x0F` are just 2 notations for the same byte-value. They are about the same 8 bits.

Comment: but the coding on the hardware needs inputs in Hex notation for processing it.

Comment: @AjeyPratapSingh you surely need to understand what you want and to clear it for us. 0x0f, or 01111b, or 15d, of "15" are different forms for the same number; for computer 0f and 15 is different only if this number is represented as string (sequence of characters), while you ask us for a way to send byte. Where do you see '15' instead of '0F' - is it debugger window or what? What is not working with this (byte) representation?

Comment: 1. When i send 0F to the hardware and read it back it gives me 15.
2. 0F is not representing a number it is the opcode for a microinstruction say I have a micro instruction "JCD xx" where opcode of JCD is 0F and xx will be an integer say 15. 
The complete instruction is "JCD 15" and i want it to be sent as "0F 15" bt using your code it's "15 15". Technically both are same that i knw.
My project is for educational purpose and students will be using hex notation for writing their assembly program in hex notation.